# iRiver T30 inaccessible (has a FAT16 partition)

Tags: windows-xp, partitioning, mp3-player, fat16

I have an iriver T30 mp3 recording device that I cannot access from any Windows XP/2k3 computer (I don't have other computers to test with).  When I plug it in, windows installs it, but it does not show up in my disk manager (diskmgmt.msc).  It does show up in My Computer as a device, but there is nothing in it.

I downloaded the iRiver Music Manager, it detects the device and shows me "FAT16 PARTITION" on it, but if I click the button, the program crashes.  Also, I have a linux box which can access the device directly just fine.  It reads it as an plain old FAT16 disk drive.

Any ideas on how to get it recognized on Windows?  Ideally, I would like to have direct disk access.

Comment: There may be other, deeper issues here but first I would suggest formatting it to fat32 or ntfs if that is a possibly.

Comment: @jmreicha I'm worried if I reformat it, the firmware will fail to access the partition.

Comment: I am *fairly* sure a format to fat 32 won't cause any problems.  If worse comes to worse you can always reformat back to fat16, should be easy to do with gparted or parted magic.  Just copy the files onto the Linux box first if you're worried about losing files.